# Query to check partitions of a table (not index) in SQLServer 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, partitioning

I'm trying to write a query that would return the partitions of a Table. It seems that sys.partitions returns only the partitions associated with indexes. Where can I find partitions associated with the table only?

[image]

I wish to retrieve the information related to **Compression > Partitions using page compression** and **Number of Partitions**.

Answer (score 1):

For heaps (table with no clustered index), the `index_id`  value in `sys.partitions` is 0. You can  get this information with

```
SELECT index_id, partition_number, rows, data_compression_desc
FROM sys.partitions 
WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Account_Partitioned);
```

Comment: So when there's a clustered index, it means both clustered index and table are partitioned?

Comment: Not necessarily since heap/clustered and non-clustered indexes can be partitioned differently using different partition functions/schemes. However, one usually partitions them similarly (i.e. aligned) to facilitate switch and other partition-level operations..